# How do I replace numbers of varying value in multiple lines of code with one specific value in a .xml file?

Tags: notepad++

First of all my apologies, I have almost zero experience in coding and I'm not familiar with any of the terminology.

And the only bit of editing software I have at the moment is Notepad++

I have multiple lines of code that, between the bits of text that identifies what the value is understood as, are short random bits of numbers. I am try to figure out how to not only easily search all of these instances of random numbers put also replace them with a pre-determined value. There are vast amounts of other code between each line that I would like to replace. Sorry again but I'll try my best to re-explain.

I'm trying to find all text line this:
(Note there are large amounts of code in between each line that I'm trying to replace and also for the example removed "<" to the other parts would show.)

- type>4523572 /type>
- type>44754 /type>
- type>98742241 /type>
- etc.

And replace with:

- type>123456789 /type>

Im just trying to replace the numbers in between.
Again my apologies if I explained this horribly. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I understand that I can use .* to select the rest of the line but it says its not able to find text

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=<type>)\d+(?=</type>)`
- Replace with: `123456789`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>